# Swift 3: CollectionView didSelectItemAt get selected cell label

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I've been struggling with this for awhile and can't find it answered elsewhere. Basically I need to edit a view inside the selected collection view cell. For example once a cell is clicked the label text inside that cell changes.

[Here is what i need however it only works on tableviews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26158768/how-to-get-textlabel-of-selected-row-in-swift)

Comment: Have you tried it yourself? Post the code and describe the errors.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If I understand it correctly you need to get the selected collection view cell:-

```
if let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
 cell.textlabel.text = "yourtext"
}
```

Comment: yes you understand correctly, however i've tried your code and it's not giving me access to the cells view such as the label. Instead i'm getting the cell's "backgroundView" , "contentView", etc..

Comment: Can you show me your code? And also check where you have added label inside it?

Comment: Worth noting that if you have subclassed your UICollectionViewCell you will need to append `as! MyCollectionViewCell` after `cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)`, where MyCollectionViewCell is the name of your subclassed cell.

Comment: @Samson, follow Tom's comments that make sense if you have subclassed cell.

Comment: you bloody legends